# Is it acceptable to ask the same question in two different Stack Exchange communities?

Tags: discussion

If you have a question which is applicable to two or more different communities but you don't get an answer in the first community you post it to, is it acceptable to ask it in one or more others? If so, how long would people suggest waiting? 24 hours or so seems fair except in urgent situations...?

An example would be the following:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275529/opensuse-leap-42-1-installs-fine-in-a-vm-but-refuses-to-dual-boot

Which has yet to receive an answer on the Linux Stack Exchange, so I'm wondering if it would be acceptable to repost in Super User...?

Comment: "except in urgent situations" - if you want an urgent answer then you need to think about alternatives.

Comment: You should also read  [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers).

Answer (score 1):

No, cross-posting is not acceptable and is generally frowned upon even if a delay is involved.

Stack Exchange already has an answer for this [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) and the answer is a resounding "NO":

> Ask the question on the site you think is most applicable. **If, like in this case, it does not get any answer, ask a moderator to migrate the question, or alternatively, delete it and re-ask it.**

If there's one thing that is disliked, it is duplicating effort across the community.  It is considered rude to ask one group of people, then ask another group entirely.  Migrating the question allows  effort to happen on one site and then be *moved* to the other site.